# How to enable HTTPS in AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, https, openssl, facebook-webhooks

I have launched Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (HVM) instance on AWS and running a Nodejs based app server.

The appserver runs fine on HTTP and I am able to get the JSON test response.

Now I need to enable HTTPS on EC2 as I need to connect this URL to Facebook Webhooks.

How to enable self-signed / free SSL on EC2 instance, so that I can provide a secured callback URL in FB webhooks?

**NOTE1:** I have open HTTPS port (443) on the EC2 instance by going to https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/ and clicking on the Security Groups link on the left, then created a new security group with also HTTPS available.

**NOTE2:** I am able to connect to FB Webhooks if I run the same app server on my local VM, using ngrok

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couple of things to check here, if you already opened port 443 in security group then check if it's been enabled in related NACL (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html) as well.
if you need free ssl certificate, you can get it from https://letsencrypt.org/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure whether facebook will redirect to a self signed url. Please do a clarification on it

Comment: @Ashan The same code runs on local machine with ngrok